# Comparar Fechas PHP y mostrar Alerta

Tags: php, mysql

Tengo el siguiente código en donde el valor de `$fecha_inicio` lo traigo desde una consulta a la BD, y lo que necesito hacer pero no se como, es que compare la fecha actual y la fecha de inicio, y si la fecha actual es mayor en 2 semanas que emita una alerta.

```php
<?php 
if($fecha_inicio != null)
{
    $fechaActual = date('d-m-Y');

    if($fechaActual > $fecha_inicio)
    {
        echo "ok, falta tiempo";
    }
    else
    {
        echo "ya pasó";
    }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bueno para dicho fin se que existe date_diff con la cual puedes calcular la cantidad de días entre 2 fechas, te dejo un [link](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.date-diff.php) para que lo revises.

No obstante te dejo un pequeño código que sé te servirá también para dicho fin. este código retorna la diferencia en segundos entre 2 fechas luego haces la conversión a días por medio de un simple calculo y con eso ya puedes usar ese valor en la condición.

```php
<?php
$fecha_inicio = "01-08-2021"; 
if($fecha_inicio != null){

$fechaActual = date('d-m-Y');
//retorna la cantidad de segundos entre las fechas 
$diff = abs(strtotime($fechaActual) - strtotime($fecha_inicio));
// para pasarlo a dias 60 segundos tiene un minuto y una hora 60
// minutos y un dia 24 horas
$diff = $diff/(60*60*24); 
// emite la alerta si es mayor a 2 semanas o sea 14 días
if($diff<14)
{
  echo "</br>ok, falta tiempo";
}
else
{
  echo "ya pasoó";
}
}
?>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, me sirvió..